# Disable Application Failure Logging on Win2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

Windows Server 2008 has by default some mechanism that automatically logs data about an application failure. I believe is called "System Queued Error Reporting".

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: I think you mean "System Queued Error Reporting".  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a 2008 machine handy to verify that they are exactly the same, but here's where you can disable it in Vista through Group Policy (using gpmc.msc for domain-level edits or gpedit.msc for local edits):

- Computer Configuration
- Administrative Templates
- System
- Internet Communication Management
- Internet Communication settings
- Turn off Windows Error Reporting: Enabled

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Server 2008, Windows Error Reporting is disabled by default. You can turn it On/Off by

1. Start -> Administrative Tools -> Server Manager.
2. Click on the machine name in Server Manager
3. Scroll down to the very bottom under **Resources and Support**.
4. Click "Turn On Windows Error Reporting"